# How can I add a service to Finder to add a movie/track to a VLC playlist?

Tags: finder, services, vlc

I am using VLC for playing videos in MacOSX 10.8, the VLC version is 2.0.5, I want a context menu in Finder with option to add a video file to vlc now playing list.

Comment: Is the regular show / hide playlist option not working for you? ![Show/Hide Playlist in VLC](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OkTV3.png)

Comment: it is working, but is there an option available to directly do it via context menu on a video file., that one is more convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Open With to make sure you open the file with VLC will add it to the current playlist

Answer (score 1):

Using the Open With to make sure you open the file with VLC will add it to the current playlist. However, this will start playing the file immediately unless you change a default setting in VLC. In VLC preferences hit the show all button in the bottom left corner. This will change the view to a list in the sidebar for the various categories. Click on "Interface", then click on "Main Interfaces", "macosx". In the panel now appearing to the right under "Behavior" uncheck the "Auto-playback of new items" option.
Now in the finder when you right click "Open With" (VLC) or "Open" (if VLC is the default app) the file will simply be added to the end of the current playlist without interrupting the currently playing file.